# What exactly is a reasonable evolutionary criterion?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, molecular-genetics

I got a rejection of publication which the reviewers mainly point out as not following a reasonable evolutionary criterion for choice of species used for phylogeny creation. In our dataset, a list of 100+ eukaryotic species was used to avoid bias. What exactly is a good "reasonable evolutionary criterion"? We are studying an ancient protein (receptor).phylogeny is created based on protein sequences.Can someone provide insight into this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.